# How can I disable my voicemail so that my caller ringtone is longer?

Tags: voicemail

How can I disable my voicemail so that my caller ringtone is longer? My phone is the Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus GT S7500.

Comment: You could try dialing `##002#`. This should disable *all* call redirects (on busy, when missed, etc.), including those to the voicemail. It's a device independent code. Please report back if it worked for you, as I'm not sure whether it's provider dependent.

Comment: The number of rings before going to voicemail is generally set by your carrier. You should get in touch with them.

Comment: Older phones had Ring quantity settings for this , after the setting was made the "cell tower" (carrier) would be sent the information. There are no such settings in my phone for this either, even though voicemail forewarding is still sent out to the tower.  If anyone got thier carrier to adjust the time or ring quantity please still answer this question.